# Discrepancy between complete.cases() and na.omit()

Tags: r

Was messing around with the Auto dataset in R.

If I run the following:

```
auto = read.csv("Auto.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings="?")
summary(complete.cases(auto))
```

I get the following:

```
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical       5     392       0
```

However, when I run this, I get different results:

```
auto1 = na.omit(auto)
dim(auto)  # returns [1] 397   9
dim(auto1) # returns [1] 392   9
```

Why does complete.cases() tell me I have no NA's but na.omit() seems to be removing some entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `complete.cases` returns a logical vector of the same length as the number of rows of the dataset while `na.omit` removes row that have at least one NA.  Using the reproducible example created below,

```
complete.cases(auto)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

As we can see, it is a logical vector with no NAs.  It gives `TRUE` for rows that doesn't have any NAs.  So, obviously, doing `summary` on a logical vector returns no NA's.

```
summary(complete.cases(auto))
#  Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
#logical       4       6       0
```

Suppose, we need to get the same result as the `na.omit`, the logical vector derived should be used to subset the original dataset

```
autoN <- auto[complete.cases(auto),]
auto1 <- na.omit(auto)
dim(autoN)
#[1] 6 2
dim(auto1)
#[1] 6 2
```

Though, the results will be similar, `na.omit` also returns some attributes

```
str(autoN)
#'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ v1: int  1 2 2 2 3 3
# $ v2: int  3 3 3 1 4 2
str(auto1)
#'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ v1: int  1 2 2 2 3 3
# $ v2: int  3 3 3 1 4 2
# - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:4] 2 7 8 10
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "2" "7" "8" "10"
```

and would be slower compared to `complete.cases` based on the benchmarks showed below.

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(238)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(NA, 1:9), 1e7, replace=TRUE),
              v2 = sample(c(NA, 1:50), 1e7, replace=TRUE))
system.time(na.omit(df1))
#  user  system elapsed 
#   2.50    0.19    2.69 
system.time(df1[complete.cases(df1),])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.61    0.09    0.70
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
auto <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace=TRUE), 
                   v2 = sample(c(NA, 1:4), 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: When, then, would I use complete.cases over na.omit and vice versa?

Comment: @kevinzakka  `na.omit` also returns some attributes and could be potentially slow compared to `complete.cases`.  Other than that, both would give the same result as long as we dont' forget to subset the dataset with `complete.cases`.  Please check my update.