# Merging two rows of data in R based on rules

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]I have merged two data frames using bind_rows. I have a situation where I have two rows of data as for example below:

```
Page Path                           Page Title             Byline      Pageviews 
/facilities/when-lighting-strikes      NA                    NA           668
/facilities/when-lighting-strikes   When Lighting Strikes  Tom Jones       NA
```

When I have these type of duplicate page paths I'd like to merge the identical page paths, eliminate the two NA's in the first row keeping the page title (When Lighting Strikes) and Byline (Tom Jones) and then keep the pageviews result of 668 from the first row. Somehow it seems that I need

1. to identify the duplicate pages paths
2. look to see if there are different titles and bylines; remove NAs
3. keep the row with the pageview result; remove the NA row

Is there a way I can do this in R dplyr? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Here's a related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509462/how-to-collapse-many-records-into-one-while-removing-na-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table` and `complete.cases`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'PathPath', loop through the columns of the dataset (`lapply(.SD, ..`) and remove the NA elements with `complete.cases`.  The `complete.cases` returns a logical `vector` and can be used for subsetting.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537231/discrepancy-between-complete-cases-and-na-omit), `complete.cases` usage is much more faster than `na.omit` and coupled with `data.table` it would increase the efficiency.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[complete.cases(x)]), by = PagePath]
#                     PagePath             PageTitle    Byline Pageviews
#1: /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes Tom Jones       668
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(PagePath = structure(c(1L, 1L), 
 .Label = "/facilities/when-lighting-strikes", class = "factor"),   
    PageTitle = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "When Lighting Strikes", class = "factor"), 
    Byline = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "Tom Jones", class = "factor"), 
    Pageviews = c(668L, NA)), .Names = c("PagePath", "PageTitle", 
"Byline", "Pageviews"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(PagePath) %>% summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
# Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
# 
#                            PagePath             PageTitle    Byline Pageviews
#                              (fctr)                (fctr)    (fctr)     (int)
# 1 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes Tom Jones       668
```

If your data is more complicated, you may need a more robust approach.

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(PagePath = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "/facilities/when-lighting-strikes", class = "factor"), 
        PageTitle = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "When Lighting Strikes", class = "factor"), 
        Byline = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "Tom Jones", class = "factor"), 
        Pageviews = c(668L, NA)), .Names = c("PagePath", "PageTitle", 
    "Byline", "Pageviews"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))
```

Comment: I should have noted that my data contains multiple rows. I'm getting a message about "expecting a single value" when I attempt to use summarise_each(funs(na.omit)).

Comment: If you post a representative subset of data, I might be able to help. If it's just that you've got some rows actually filled in correctly already, you could wrap in `unique` to collapse: `summarise_each(funs(unique(na.omit(.))))`. Otherwise you may need to group by another variable if you're shooting for more than one result row for each group.

Comment: I've posted a more respresentative data sample to the original question and have highlighted two rows. So for instance I would like to merge the two identical pagePaths /facilities/management-operators/when-lighting-strikes. In merging I would like to preserve the pageTitle and byline from the second row and the pageviews from the top row.

Comment: Don't post images of data, because other people can't import them, instead [post the results of `dput(head(df))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). It looks like it's the other columns you didn't initially show that are causing you problems, though; the `unique` approach above should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use replace function in for loop

for(i in unique(df$Page_Path)){
  df$Pageviews[df$Page_Path==i] <- replace(df$Pageviews[df$Page_Path==i],is.na(df$Pageviews[df$Page_Path==i]),
    df$Pageviews[!is.na(df$Pageviews[df$Page_Path==i])])
}

df <- subset(df, !is.na(Page_Title))

print(df)

                          Page_Path            Page_Title    Byline Pageviews
2 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes Tom Jones       668
```

Comment: Thank you. I attempted to implement, but end up with all NA pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (similar to a previous solutions that uses dplyr) would be:

```
  df %>% group_by(PagePath) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(PageTitle = paste(na.omit(PageTitle)),
                   Byline = paste(na.omit(Byline)),
                   Pageviews =paste(na.omit(Pageviews)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the below but when I attempt to view I get an error: expecting a single value. I've tried the below using dplyr:: rename(byline = dimension2) %>% dplyr::rename(Site = profileName)%>% group_by(pagePath)%>%dplyr::summarize(pageTitle = paste(na.omit(pageTitle)),byline = paste(na.omit(byline)),pageviews=paste(na.omit(pageviews))). I should mention that this is Google Analytics data.

Comment: Can you provide some example data for which you get this error? It would be easier to solve this if we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using **fill**. Using `tidyverse` 1.3.0+ with `dplyr` 0.8.5+, you can use **fill** to fill in missing values.

See this for more information https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html

**DATA** Thanks Alistaire

```
df <- structure(list(PagePath = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "/facilities/when-lighting-strikes", class = "factor"), 
        PageTitle = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "When Lighting Strikes", class = "factor"), 
        Byline = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = "Tom Jones", class = "factor"), 
        Pageviews = c(668L, NA)), .Names = c("PagePath", "PageTitle", 
    "Byline", "Pageviews"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   PagePath [1]
  PagePath                          PageTitle             Byline    Pageviews
  <fct>                             <fct>                 <fct>         <int>
1 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes NA                    NA              668
2 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes Tom Jones        NA
```

**CODE**

I just did this for *PageTitle* but you can repeat fill to do it for other columns. (`dplyr` gurus might have a smarter way to do all 3 columns at once). If you have ordered data like dates, then you can set `.direction` to be just down for example (look at past data).

```
df.new <- df %>% group_by(PagePath) 
             %>% fill(PageTitle, .direction = "updown")
```

which gives you

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   PagePath [1]
  PagePath                          PageTitle             Byline    Pageviews
  <fct>                             <fct>                 <fct>         <int>
1 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes NA              668
2 /facilities/when-lighting-strikes When Lighting Strikes Tom Jones        NA
```

Once you have all the NAs cleaned up then you can use distinct or rank to get your final summarised dataframe.